# Ajax saving array into global variables not working keep getting undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Trying to save an array retrieved from ajax into a global variable such that I may use it later on but keep getting undefined error

```
   <script>
    var items = [];

    function add(value){
        items.push(value);
    }

    $(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'xxxx.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            for(i=0; i < result.length; i++){
                add(result[i]);
            }
        },
    });
    });

    document.write(items[1])

    </script>
```

Comment: Which line is returning an error?

Comment: document.write(items[1]) is spitting out undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajaxstop to call the method after the ajax request has completed. Place the following function in document ready:

```
 $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
     document.write(items[1]);      
 });
```

The above solution works but this is another option I used when waiting for multiple ajax functions to complete. This will call every time you complete an ajax request but there is a way to limit to one call if need be.

Comment: What would the method be to limit to one call?

Comment: I created a function that made the ajax call and included this code $(document).one('ajaxStop', function () { yourfunction(); });

Comment: it gives me the value i want but the issue i had was that it cause everything else in the html to disappear and only displaying the value would it be better to use innerHTML?

Comment: <input type="radio" name="MonSafe" value="4"> 4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="MonSafe" value="5"> 5&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Current average: <a id="item4"></a>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
document.write(items[1]);      
});
</script>

Comment: If you are just trying to add the result of items[1] to demo you don't need document.write. Just assign it in the ajaxstop function. yourelement.innerHTML = items[1].

Comment: so my array has about 50 or so variables so i need to do it multiple times is there a easier way such that i don't need to have a id=xxx and just spit the variable out which is what i thought document write would do but if it clears the page and just gives me the variable that doesn't help me

Comment: If you are not looking for specific results and just want to print all of them just have a global variable items with an empty string and concatenate them in a for loop for each result. var items = ''; Inside the success of ajax for loop do this: items += result[i] + '<br>'; Then in the ajaxstop do this: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = string;

Comment: Thats assuming you want a line break to separate the results you can add whatever html code you want there

Answer (score 1):

This is an asynchronous AJAX call. The call to `add` will be done at a later time than the execution of `document.write(items[1]);`

So this is the right way to do it:

```
<script>
    var items = [];

    function add(value){
        items.push(value);
    }

$(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'xxxx.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            for(i=0; i < result.length; i++){
                add(result[i]);
            }
            document.write(items[1])
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

This way the function that uses the result, will be executed when the result function is executed.

Think it this way: you said: Here is this lemon basket. Then you asked someone to go somewhere and get the lemons and before he returned you tried to count the lemons. Got it ?

Comment: To be explicit, when `document.write(items[1]);` is called, `items[1]` is still `undefined` because `items` is an empty array.

Comment: I see, but I want to be able to use it outside and store that variable into a global variable. I know it works if i put it inside but wasn't what i was going for.

Comment: It will be stored outside. The for loop correctly populates items. It's just not available immediately. But as soon as the ajax returns it will be.

Comment: Well you are calling items[1] also are you sure there are 2 or more items being added to the array? If 1 or less items are added it will always be undefined

Comment: @bryangators55 has a point. Shenron, notice that you're writing the 2nd element in the array (`items[1]`)

Comment: I used 1 just as an example the others are available I've checked those.